# Draw a certain UI element only after it's fully loaded in Android

Tags: android, performance, graph, android-asynctask, android-viewpager

I'm currently working with a ViewPager in Android.

Every fragment represents a certain element, which is plotted inside the corresponding page using this library (http://www.android-graphview.org/).
If you have been working with Viewpagers, you probably know they load 3 pages, the one to the right, the current one and the one to the left. When I start the app, it loads and then draws the 3 current plots (left, middle, right). Now every of these plots is quite large, so it takes some time to load and draw them (about 3 seconds). If a user now swipes left, the animation is really smooth, because the one to the left is already preloaded and drawn. If the user now swipes left instantly again, the graph is not yet fully loaded and drawn, so my app freezes for the remaining time until the data is plotted.

Question is:
Can I achieve smooth animations while the graphs are loading in background, and only plot them once they are finished loading? Tried it with ASyncTask, but that only manages to crash my app once in every while.

This is OnCreateView of the page:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pager_list, container, false);
        View tv = v.findViewById(R.id.pagertext);
        ((TextView) tv).setText("Fragment #" + mNum);
        Calendar date = new GregorianCalendar();
        date.add(Calendar.DATE, -29 + mNum);
        Log.d("date", String.valueOf(-29 + mNum));
        String datestring = (String.valueOf(date.get(GregorianCalendar.YEAR))) + "-"
                + (String.valueOf(date.get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH) + 1)) + "-"
                + (String.valueOf(date.get(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)));
        //FILL THE GRAPH WITH DATA FOR THE CURRENT DAY
        // currently sample data to see if it's working dynamically.
        DailyCooldown cooldown = new DailyCooldown(date.getTime());
        GraphView graph = (GraphView) v.findViewById(R.id.graphtoday);
        TextView text = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textV1);
        new PlotGraphsTask(graph, text, v.getContext()).execute(cooldown);
        // FIll the textviews below with the appropriate data
        TextView intensity = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.intensity);
        intensity.setText("Intensity: " + String.valueOf(cooldown.alpha2min));
        TextView dalda = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.dalda);
        dalda.setText("DALDA scale: " + String.valueOf(cooldown.DALDA));
        TextView rpe = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.rpe);
        rpe.setText("RPE scale: " + String.valueOf(cooldown.RPE));
        return v;
    }
```

And this is the ASyncTask I'm currently using:

```
private static class PlotGraphsTask extends AsyncTask<DailyCooldown, Void, Void> {
    public GraphView graph;
    public TextView text;
    public Context context;
    public PlotGraphsTask(GraphView arggraph, TextView argtext, Context argcontext){
        this.graph = arggraph;
        this.text = argtext;
        this.context = argcontext;
    }
    protected Void doInBackground(DailyCooldown... cooldown) {
        GraphView[] graphs = {graph};
        TextView[] labels = new TextView[]{text};
        VisualizationsPlotter.Plot(cooldown[0].visualizations, graphs, labels, context);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why your app crashes is that doInBackground() method doesn't have a connection with UI thread, which is the main thread of android app. And your app freezes because you are plotting graphs in the main thread (that takes some time and freez your application for 3 secs).

But `onProgressUpdate()` method have connection wuth UI thread, and you can draw your graph manualy, point by point, from this method.